# Eclipse search a string by excluding some part

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to search a string in eclipse.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />

<input type="text" sacsacdfsre />
```

I want to search all input elements of type text and exclude elements with autocomplete.

```
Search input and text and exclude autocomplete
```

I am trying

```
  input.*text.*^(autocomplete)
```

how can we solve this.

Comment: I think that you need to [learn regular expressions](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/) as putting `^` in the middle of your expression doesn't make sense at all in this situation.

Comment: @HamZa. Thank you. Can you tell me what exactly do I use here.

Comment: Yes I could but when will you learn ? I'll give you a start and it's up to you to make it better [`<input\s+type="text"(?:(?!autocomplete=)[^>])+>`](http://regex101.com/r/nI8bD6)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<input[^>]+type="text"(?![^>]*autocomplete).*?>
```

[Working example on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%3Cinput%5B%5E%3E%5D%2atype%3D%22text%22%28%3F!%5B%5E%3E%5D%2aautocomplete%29.%2a%3F%3E&input=%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20autocomplete%3D%22off%22%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20sacsacdfsre%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20autocomplete%3D%22off%22%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20sacsacdfsre%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20autocomplete%3D%22off%22%20%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type%3D%22text%22%20sacsacdfsre%20%2F%3E)